# Making all 16 Combination of Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen

So there are 4 types of screen sizes `small`,`medium`,`large` and `x-large` and 4 types of screen density `ldpi`,`mdpi`,`hdpi` and `xhdpi`.
Do anyone know of any tutorial about how can I make all 16 kinds of emulators using Eclipse IDE.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **Table 3** under **How to Test Your Application on Multiple Screens**
 http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for finding the official page, I must have ignored it. Let me make all 16 types of emulator first using the link ;)

Comment: Proper Link - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing