# List of all the Android screen sizes

Tags: android, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231856/android-screen-sizes)

Where can I find a definative list of all the Android device screen resolutions?

Comment: Google might be a better place to get an answer to this question.  Or searching [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231856/android-screen-sizes), on [so]

Comment: There is no definitive list of screen *resolutions*. Any device manufacturer is welcome to create devices with whatever resolution they want.

Answer (score 0):

Search on [Official Android site](http://developer.android.com) for better understanding about screen-sizes and resolutions. Mainly there are four types of resolution range - ldpi,mpdi,hdpi and xhdpi.
Look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696441/making-all-16-combination-of-emulator) too for more info.